# How do i full size background with SVG on flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg, mobile

i have code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class Onboarding_Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Onboarding_Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String assetName = ('assets/svg/Artboard1.svg');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  assetName,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so how to fit on any side to my mobile?. it seems like spare space on left bottom right top.
here is my app debug:

[image]

thanks in advice

Comment: can you provide the svg?

Comment: you found the solution?

Comment: @MunsifAli ah i see. the problem is SVG itself on view screen. solved

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the SvgPicture widget in Positioned.fill()

Code:

```
class WidgetName extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetName({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              assetName,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing happen when i wrap svgpicture in Positioned.fill()

Comment: Strange, it works for me